# how to use spread operator in conjunction with Math.min() on an array of objects to find the min of a value in spread objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects, where one of the keys holds the distance (int), I would like to spread only those values and pop out the correct object.

`elevatorDistances` holds all the objects from the following statement iterated by each elevator and the distance from the floor it was called from:

```
elevators.forEach(elevator => {
    let distanceFromCall = Math.abs(elevator.current_floor - calledFromStorey).toFixed(2);
    elevatorDistances.push({id:elevator.id,distance:distanceFromCall})
});
```

At this point I would like to extrapolate the minimum distance (`distanceFromCall`) in the most terse way, I was thinking something in the lines of this pseudo: `Math.min(...elevatorDistances['distance'])`.

What would be the right way to write the above pseudo to find the most minimal distance in the array of objects `elevatorDistances`?

Comment: Could you post a template of the array - how the array is supposed to look?

Comment: "I would like to spread only those values and pop out the correct object." Do not overthink. A simple loop would be more readable and efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to map the values and then spread them.

```
Math.min(...elevatorDistances.map(e => e.distance));
```

Update

I think I know what you're trying to do. You actually want the elevator object to "pop out" from some terse functional expression. Well, Math.min only returns numbers, so you can't use that. A reducer can help you.

```
const closestElevator = elevators.reduce((current, next) => 
    Math.abs(current.current_floor - calledFromStorey) < 
        Math.abs(next.current_floor - calledFromStorey) ? current : next);
```

Now, as others have noted, this may not be legible, but I think it's what you wanted as far as a terse expression. You actually get the object instead of the distance alone. But, surely, a classic for loop is more efficient.

Comment: Thanks Alex 100% what I was looking for.